# Are Macbook Pro Pre-Unibody Top Case Parts Interchangeable?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, case, non-unibody

I have a question for service engineers here.

I wonder if and where I can source top case (with keyboard) from any pre-unibody MBP for my beaten and torn A1150 one (Core Duo original MBP)

Comment: Between which two models?

Comment: There were few pre unibody 15 inch MBP models codenamed A1150, A1211(Core2Duo), A1226 and A1260(Nvidia)